# Creating an Example to Teach "Confidence Intervals"

Tags: r, probability, confidence-interval

Usually, people tend to confuse the interpretation of confidence intervals. The following two statements are said to be quite confusing (even to myself):

- A 95% Confidence Interval means that the population parameter will be contained within this interval with a probability of 0.95 (incorrect)
- A 95% Confidence Interval means that the Confidence Interval itself has a 0.95 probability of containing the population parameter (less incorrect)

**I was wondering if it is possible to create some example (e.g., an R simulation) which shows that why one of the above statements is more correct than the other.**

I found this post here [The importance of a correct interpretation of a confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472455/the-importance-of-a-correct-interpretation-of-a-confidence-interval) in which R code is provided that simulates data to illustrate these concepts.

**But is it possible to create an example in which it becomes clear that interpreting a confidence interval as "the probability of the population parameter being contained within this interval" is clearly incorrect or results in a contradiction?**

Perhaps someone can think of such an example or provide a link/reference to such an example?

Comment: A clearly  incorrect example: $\mu = 10$, $\bar{x}=12$, and 95% CI is $(10.2, 13.8)$. $Pr\left[(10.2 < \mu) \cap (\mu < 13.8)\right] = 0$, despite 95% confidence level.

Comment: While this can be an interesting question and a potentially useful one for teaching the green horns, one must tread carefully with "incorrect" interpretations: they are incorrect. Casella and Berger elaborated and beautifully explained the conundrum and the actual correct interpretation, which is briefly stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/586136/362671).

Comment: Seems to be like a philosophical point which would be difficult to establish with a sim study.

Comment: We have several very highly voted threads addressing the subtleties of confidence intervals with many answers posted to each: see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22confidence+interval%22+score%3A100)

Comment: Aside: There is a relatively straightforward and useful interpretation of frequentist confidence intervals: **This interval estimates a *plausible range of values* for the true parameter at a given level of confidence.** This deemphasizes the meaning of the Type I error rate (i.e. the 'reproducing the study a large number of times…' bit) without dispensing with it entirely.